# Result not showing in Input text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following JQuery code I am working on. When I test it, the expected values are shown in the span but not in the input text box.

JQ

```
$(function() {
    $("#textbox").each(function() {
        var input = '#' + this.id;
        counter(input);
        $(this).keyup(function() {
            counter(input);
        });
    });
});

function counter(field) {
    var number = 0;
    var text = $(field).val();
    var word = $(field).val().split(/[ \n\r]/);
    words = word.filter(function(word) {
        return word.length > 0 && word.match(/^[A-Za-z0-9]/);
    }).length;
        $('.wordCount').text(words);
        $('#sentencecount').text(words);
}
```

Please see [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6B9Ga/6/). Please let me know where I have gone wrong. Still new to JS.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this:

```
$('#sentencecount').text(words);
```

to this:

```
$('#sentencecount').val(words);
```

The .text() method cannot be used on form inputs or scripts. To set or get the text value of input or textarea elements, use the .val() method. To get the value of a script element, use the .html() method. -> http://api.jquery.com/text/

Comment: ah Bravo, i just read it somewhere else just now. Thanks and sorry for waisting your time. Will accept in 10mins time

Answer (score 1):

Trying using [`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) instead This should fix it up.

http://jsfiddle.net/josephs8/6B9Ga/8/

Answer (score 0):

You can not set text to an input you must use value 
try this.

```
$('#sentencecount').text(words);
//has to be
$('#sentencecount').val(words);
```

and i have also updated your Jsfiddle

```
$(function() {
    $("#textbox").each(function() {
        var input = '#' + this.id;
        counter(input);
        $(this).keyup(function() {
            counter(input);
        });
    });
});

function counter(field) {
    var number = 0;
    var text = $(field).val();
    var word = $(field).val().split(/[ \n\r]/);
    words = word.filter(function(word) {
        return word.length > 0 && word.match(/^[A-Za-z0-9]/);
    }).length;
        $('.wordCount').text(words);
        $('#sentencecount').val(words);
}
```